# In OCaml, how to store "pointers" to elements of a list?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a list of some data type. However, I also want to index the elements of that list with a trie, so I can do more efficient lookups. But I don't want to store the same elements twice, so I want to store the elements in the list, and in the trie I store pointers to elements, in the leaf nodes. Is this possible? I *could* store the index of the element in the list, however getting an element of a linked list by index is slow, so that won't do.

Apologies if this is a misunderstanding of the OCaml memory model.

Comment: Anything against using a map for element storage?

Comment: I need to store the elements in order of addition (like a stack). But I also need to efficiently index then with a trie.

Comment: In OCaml, we only have pointers to blocks and immediate values. There's nothing special to do to preserve sharing when passing values around, if that's what you're worried about. Blocks such as arrays, records, etc. are never copied implicitly because we only ever manipulate pointers to them.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the element. Under the hood, this doesn't copy the value, it just copies a pointer to the value, except for values that are stored in a single memory word (just like a  pointer).

In other words, things like `let b = a` do *not* make a copy `a`. They make `b` an alias of `a`.

Values are automatically shared in Ocaml. The only case where you wouldn't want sharing is a mutable object (reference, or structure or object with mutable fields). If you want two mutable objects with the same current value but such that an assignment will only affect one of the objects, then you need to make a copy.